# Why doesn't my function work for large numbers and how can I change it?

Tags: c++, modulo

I have found a formula that solves a problem but I can't make it work for large numbers. The n-th factor would be the (n-1)-th factor + (n-1)*(n-1) + n * n

So I wrote this function:

```
inline long long int formula(long long int n)
{
    if(n==1)return 1;
    return formula(n-1)+(n-1)*(n-1)+*n*n;
}
```

and since the answer has to be calculated modulo 666013, I added this (MOD=666013):

```
inline long long int formula(long long int n)
{
    if(n==1)return 1;
    return ((formula(n-1)%MOD+(1LL*(n-1)*(n-1))%MOD)%MOD+(1LL*n*n)%MOD)%MOD;
}
```

I probably didn't use modulo correctly. My function has to work for numbers as large as 2.000.000.000 and it stops working at about 30.000

EDIT: I've tried using a loop and I still can't make it work for numbers larger than 20.000.000. This is what I'm using:

```
ans=1;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ans=(ans%MOD+1LL*(i-1)*(i-1)%MOD+1LL*i*i%MOD)%MOD;
    }
```

Comment: Your recursion is causing stack overflow most likely.

Comment: Large numbers, that means the function will call itself recursively many times. You will need 2000000000 items on the stack. Hm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will take quite a long time if you need to calculate it for size of 2 billion. However, the recursive equation leads trivially to

```
sum [i * i+(i-1)*(i-1)] = sum [2* i * i - 2*i + 1].
```

You can use the equation for [the sum of first n squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers) and the arithmetic sequence to simplify this to:

```
2*n(n * n + 1) / 3
```

Now you can further reduce this using a * b % c = (a % c) * (b %c). However, the division by 3 and modulus operation does not commute. So you need to write the equation as

`( ((2*(n % MOD)) %MOD) * (((n % MOD) * (n % MOD)) +1) %MOD) * 444009) % MOD`,

where the 444009 is the modular inverse of 3 mod MOD, i.e, 3*444009 % MOD =1.

*EDIT:* Added the discussion about commuting modulus and division operators as pointed out by Raymond Chen the modulus and division do not commute.

Comment: Thank you very much! There is no need to use  a loop or a recursive function. This is the correct solution.

Comment: Note that instead of dividing by 3, you need to multiply by 444009, since division doesn't commute with modulo.

Comment: @RaymondChen, does that have anything to do with the modular multiplicative inverse?  While the program works, the answers are not always right. I think I'm misusing the modulo operation. My code:  `ans=(((1LL*(n%MOD-1)*(n%MOD)*(1LL*2*n%MOD-1))/3)%MOD+1LL*n*n%MOD)%MOD;`

Comment: Thank for they correction Raymond I'll  edit the answer

Comment: @M.Ritz As I said, division doesn't commute with modulo. `(a / b) mod c` is not equal to `(a mod c) / b`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Ok, I've figured I need to use the modular multiplicative inverse, so /3 becomes *3^(MOD-2), but I still don't seem to get the results right. May you please help me with placing the modulo operations?   `ans=((1LL*(1LL*((n%MOD-1)*(n%MOD))*(1LL*2*n%MOD-1))*exp(3,MOD-2))%MOD+1LL*(n%MOD)*(n%MOD))%MOD; `   exp is a function that calculates 3^(MOD-2) =444009

Comment: You need to debug it. Break the expression down and check the value of each subexpression. Note also that the `%` operator behaves non-mathematically on negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are using a recursive function for this. It will work at a low number of calls, but if you recursively call it a few milion times, well... it will not. The reason is that you are calling a function within another function within another function... too many times provoking the program to collapse or named as "Stack Overflow".

The best possible way to overcome this, is to use a loop to fix it up! Just iterate from 0 to n (n being the number you want to obtain).

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I did and it now works for larger numbers, but I still can't make it work if the numbers are larger than about 20.000.000.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify as much as possible in order to be able to see the requirements:

```
typedef long long val_t;
#define MOD         ((val_t) 666013)

// for really big numbers, change #if to 1
#if 0
#define MODOF(_x)   ((_x) % MOD)
#else
#define MODOF(_x)   (_x)
#endif

#define SQR(_i)     MODOF((_i) * (_i))

val_t
formula(val_t n)
{
    val_t i;
    val_t ans;

    ans = 0;

    for (i = 1;  i <= n;  ++i) {
        ans += SQR(i-1);
        ans += SQR(i);
        ans %= MOD;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

UPDATE: I'm so used to seeing factorial herein that I wrote the wrong formula.  Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative version of your code is in below . You can use it

```
    inline long long int formula(long long int n)
    {
        long long f = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            f = ((f % MOD + (1LL * (i - 1)*(i - 1)) % MOD) % MOD + (1LL * i*i) % MOD) % MOD;
        }
        return f;
    }
```